# Delete rest skills list which don't match in csv file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, stop-words

I want to delete the rest of skills which don't match these skills.
Skills exist in csv file.
When I run this happened this problem:

```
skills_csv = pd.read_csv("Skills.csv")
new_stopwords = skills_csv["Skills"].tolist()

# remove new stop words
new_stop = stop.extend(new_stopwords)
df_result["skills_list"] = df_result["skills_list"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x 
in x.split() if x in new_stop))
df_result
```

this error happened:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [23], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # remove new stop words
      2 new_stop = stop.extend(new_stopwords)
----> 3 df_result["skills_list"] = df_result["skills_list"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x in new_stop))
      4 df_result

File F:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:4433, in Series.apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4323 def apply(
   4324     self,
   4325     func: AggFuncType,
   (...)
   4328     **kwargs,
   4329 ) -> DataFrame | Series:
   4330     """
   4331     Invoke function on values of Series.
   4332 
   (...)
   4431     dtype: float64
   4432     """
-> 4433     return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()

File F:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1082, in SeriesApply.apply(self)
   1131         values = obj.astype(object)._values
   1132         # error: Argument 2 to "map_infer" has incompatible type
   1133         # "Union[Callable[..., Any], str, List[Union[Callable[..., Any], str]],
   1134         # Dict[Hashable, Union[Union[Callable[..., Any], str],
   1135         # List[Union[Callable[..., Any], str]]]]]"; expected
   1136         # "Callable[[Any], Any]"
-> 1137         mapped = lib.map_infer(
   1138             values,

File F:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx:2870, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

Input In [23], in <lambda>(x)
      1 # remove new stop words
      2 new_stop = stop.extend(new_stopwords)
----> 3 df_result["skills_list"] = df_result["skills_list"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x in new_stop))
      4 df_result

Input In [23], in <genexpr>(.0)
      1 # remove new stop words
      2 new_stop = stop.extend(new_stopwords)
----> 3 df_result["skills_list"] = df_result["skills_list"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x in new_stop))
      4 df_result

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I hope this problem can be solved easily and quickly please.
I'm waiting for you............

Answer (score 0):

- if you want filter out `None`

```py
skills_csv = pd.read_csv("Skills.csv")
new_stopwords = skills_csv["Skills"].tolist()

# remove new stop words
new_stop = stop.extend(new_stopwords)
df_result = df_result.dropna(how="any") #  <--- add here
df_result["skills_list"] = df_result["skills_list"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(y for y in x.split() if y in new_stop)) #  <--- modify a variable name
df_result
```

- if you want ignore `None`

```py
skills_csv = pd.read_csv("Skills.csv")
new_stopwords = skills_csv["Skills"].tolist()

# remove new stop words
new_stop = stop.extend(new_stopwords)
df_result["skills_list"] = df_result["skills_list"].apply(lambda x: x if (x is None) else (" ".join(y for y in x.split() if (y in new_stop) and not (y is None))) )
df_result
```

Comment: The same Problem.

Comment: Do you have another solution?